# overide the vuetify button text color

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

How do I override the default active color for a button text in a toolbar:

```
v-btn(:to="item.path" active-class="v-btn--active toolbar-btn-active") {{item.meta.title}}
```

I created this class to try to override it:

```
.toolbar-btn-active {
  background-color: white;
  &::before {
    background-color: white;
  }
  .v-btn__content {
    color: red !important;
   }
}
```

Only the background works. How do I modify my css to update the button color?

This is the rendered html:

```
<a href="/document" class="v-btn v-btn--active toolbar-btn-active">
           <div class="v-btn__content">Document</div>
</a>
```

Comment: you can append "--text" to color class e.g. `<v-btn class="white--text">`. Or you mean changing the global var?

Comment: meant when it is active

Comment: `v-btn--active` is default active class so `.v-btn--active .v-btn__content{ color: red }` should change it. Can you provide [codepen](https://template.vuetifyjs.com) perhaps?

Comment: thanks that worked: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QBowGx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`v-btn--active` is default active class(can be changed with `active-class` prop).

So we can target active-class and modify CSS like so:

```
.v-btn--active .v-btn__content { 
  color: red 
}
```

Note in scoped style we need to use deep selectors `>>>`:

```
>>> .v-btn--active .v-btn__content
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply changes to specified button in html you can add class to v-btn

```
<v-btn class="primary">Button</v-btn>

<style>
.primary {
  color: yellow !important;
  background-color: blue !important;
}
</style>
```